# Add search feature to simple website without mySQL database

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine, google-custom-search

I have a simple HTML site with 100+ pages or so. I want to add a search bar at the top so the user can search the site. I know about [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/), but it shows ads unless you pay at least $100. Obviously I'd like ad-less search on my site for free if at all possible!

I've also heard about Lucene/Solr, but they do not actually *crawl* the site. For that I would apparently need Nutch.

Anyway, the site I have runs on a Microsoft IIS6 server, but I have basically no knowledge as to how Solr, Nutch, etc. gets "installed" on the server.

**Also:** I'd like to point out that I do have a local copy of the site. Perhaps I can do one big initial nutch "crawl" locally that will create an .xml for Solr?? That would help me get "up and running", but probably wouldn't be a good long-term solution.

..so should I just use Google Custom Search? or is there a not-extremely-painful-to-implement alternative? The brain hurts folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention how many search requests you want to handle but if you use the [json-rest-api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) of google's custom search you have 100 searchqueries a day for free and you can display them without any ads on your page.

An simple example request can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 100 queries/day may actually suffice, but I am not sure. I intend to watch Google Analytics to see how often the search feature gets used. And hopefully the search won't get spammed by some bot..

Comment: The API has a parameter to quota all users so you can stop bots from spamming your search.

Comment: To clarify, I believe you can only set a per-second quota for all users. I was hoping there would be a way to specifically set per-user daily quotas i.e. only allot 10 searches max per user. More info here: https://developers.google.com/console/help/#cappingusage

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way that works pretty well, although you may be looking for something more than this.

http://sitecomber.com/getsitecomber/

You can create code to paste into your site in about 2 minutes.  It doesn't get easier than that.  Search is powered by Google, but results are isolated to your website.

EDIT: This no longer works.